# Phonegap argument is truncated after "=" (using plugin) : Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to pass a base64 string to native android , using phonegap plugin:

```
cordova.exec(function(winParam) {}, function(error) {}, "service",
             "action", [base64String]);
```

The issue is the the received string is truncated after some characters.
This is not a static limit(as i have tried for various images) but after lots of investigation, found that an **=** is being received in the last character of the received string.

```
int myLength = args.getString(0).length();
Log.v(TAG,Character.toString(args.getString(0).charAt(myLength-1)));
```

I know that = is inserted at the end of the base  64 string if its not a multiple of 3. But its a guess that an **=** is being inserted somewhere between the javascript call and java /plugin received.

Can someone throw some light on it ?

Comment: Can you just encodeUrlComponent in javascript and decode it in java with URLDecoder.decode(param, "UTF-8")?

Comment: @Noogen : Thanks, but the same issue persists.